# Subworkflow example is not work in flowgear

Tags: flowgear

I have created two flowgear workflow for demo purpose and understanding how to work flowgear SubWorkflow.I have created two flowgear workflow ex.below is the link:

1)Test1:http://flowgear.me/s/ovY8mH9

2)Test2:http://flowgear.me/#s/20vD6P6

In Test1 workflow drag one SubWorkflow Node and set appropriate property.

In workflow id property i have set Test2 workflow id.
When i run Test1 flowgear workflow the SubWorkflow gives the following error:
        **Invalid Site or Workflow**

Answer (score 1):

The `SubWorkflow` node is depricated, and you should use the `Workflow` node.

At this stage, you will have to do this using the [Old Console](https://my.flowgear.net/slhost/install). You must right-click on the node, and then `Choose Workflow`